# How do I build a shared library using Go that calls an undefined c function?

Tags: cgo

I want to create a shared library, using Go, to be used by a third-party software ([STAR-CCM+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simcenter_STAR-CCM%2B)).  That software provides some utility c functions for my code to call, and expects my code to, *at a minimum*, define a specific function, which the third-party software will call after loading the library.

My problem is Go complains about undefined references for the utility functions:

```
/tmp/go-build672782048/b001/_x002.o: In function `_cgo_c4b84da031f3_Cfunc_utility':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:50: undefined reference to `utility'
```

How can I compile a shared library that calls a c function that is declared but not defined by my code?

The third-party software provides a header file similar to this:

**uclib.h**

```cpp
#ifndef UCLIB_H
#define UCLIB_H

// utility function defined by third party software, declared here
extern void utility(int);

// function expected to exist in .so and defined by user
// this function is expected to call `utility` one or more times
void user_function();

#endif
```

### Working example, *c only*

To test the interaction with the third party software, I build an example using only c:

**usingc.c**

```cpp
#include "uclib.h"

void
user_function()
{
    utility(1);
}
```

Build:

```
$ gcc -fPIC -c usingc.c -o usingc.o
$ gcc -shared -o libmine.so usingc.o
```

This results in a `libmine.so` that the third party software successfully loads and registers its `utility` function being called with `1`.  Note that `utility` was only declared, never defined, by my code.

### Problematic example, Go

I create a simple go module with the header above and two files:

**go.mod**

```
module example.com/cgo_mwe

go 1.15
```

**usinggo.go**

```golang
package main

// #include "uclib.h"
import "C"

//export user_function
func user_function() {
    C.utility(C.int(2))
}

func main() {}
```

I attempt to build the shared library and observe the error:

```
$ go build -o libmineg.so -buildmode=c-shared
# example.com/cgo_mwe
/tmp/go-build672782048/b001/_x002.o: In function `_cgo_c4b84da031f3_Cfunc_utility':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:50: undefined reference to `utility'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are three possible solutions to allow the linking with the undefined reference.  The second two are found in the [`golang-nuts` Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/NPEKogRR9Q0/m/pklMzMd6CAAJ):

1. ignore all undefined references via `LDFLAGS` with `-shared`

```cpp
// #include "uclib.h"
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -shared
import "C"
```

2. ignore all undefined references via `LDFLAGS` with `-Wl,-unresolved-symbols=ignore-all`:

```cpp
// #include "uclib.h"
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -Wl,-unresolved-symbols=ignore-all
import "C"
```

3. mark the declared but undefined functions [as weak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol) in the header file:

```cpp
#pragma weak utility
// utility function defined by third party software, declared here
extern void utility(int);
```

The advantage of #3 is that references not marked weak are still called out as undefined.